# Enable fullscreen by default for Desktop Entry of Terminal applications

Tags: launcher, desktop-environments, cmus

I have created this Desktop Entry for terminal application `cmus`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=cmus
GenericName=C Music Player
Comment=Music Player for Unix-like systems
Exec=/home/udiboy/.local/bin/cmus
Icon=/home/udiboy/.local/bin/cmus.png
Terminal=true
Categories=Application;
```

It opens a terminal with `cmus` properly, but it's not fullscreen. Is there a way to open the terminal window in fullscreen by default?